# Dynamic for loops

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to build a program which uses two for loops and when called should print out:

> ```
>       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>  2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
> 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
> etc.
> ```

```
let mutable s:string = ""

let loopMulTable n = 
  for i in 1..10 do
    s <- sprintf "%i " (n*i)
    printf "%s " s
    for j in n-1 do
      s <- sprintf "%i " (n*i)
loopMulTable 2
```

Right now I am not too concerned about the spacing, just making the right prints.

I am not sure whats wrong with my  `for j in n-1 do` loop but it gives me the error: FS0043: The type 'int32' is not compatible with the type seq<'a>.

I probably need to do some type of casting, but not sure how.

Thank you!

Figured out a solution:

```
let mutable s:string = ""

let loopMulTable n = 
  for i in 1..n do
    printf "\n"
    for j in 1..10 do
      s <- sprintf "%5i " (i*j)
      printf "%s " s
loopMulTable 10
```

Comment: `n-1` is a number - you probably meant `a .. (n-1)` for some a

Comment: Oh! haha yeah thanks man!

Comment: Since others will be reading your code it's a good idea to be concerned with spacing...

Comment: I didn't mean spacing in the code itself. Meant spacing in the output.
I know you need more spaces in the code for readability, but I cant use tab in my editor, and blasting the space button all the time for tasks like this is just ugh.

Comment: You don't need that mutable string; `printf "%5i " (i*j)` will do. Addding unnecessary mutable data is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: You can post your own answer and even accept it if you like it.

Comment: If you got the answer to your question, you should accept it.

Comment: I mean the previous questions, too.

Comment: I know I don't need the string, but needed to store the result somewhere, and thought a string would be fine? Also I added the string as the return value so I could call the function later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution:

```
let mutable s:string = ""

let loopMulTable n = 
  for i in 1..10 do
    s <- sprintf "%i " (n*i)
    printf "%s " s
    for j in n-1 do
      s <- sprintf "%i " (n*i)
    s
loopMulTable 2
```

Comment: If you really want that string s, place it inside the function. Or just skip it and say let s = loopMultable 2.

Comment: Aaah yeah ofc. Makes sense to just assign it in the end! Actually thought of that, don't know why I didn't do it. Good call!

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun here's a more idiomatic version:

```
[for i in 1..10 ->
    List.init 10 (fun j -> (j+1)*i)]
```